# Swagger UI Express - Cannot GET /docs/

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

I implemented a simple server with integrating Swagger documentation. My simple code as following

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const YAML = require('yamljs');

const serverPort = 8080;
const app = express();

const swaggerDoc = YAML.load('./api/swagger.yaml');

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false,
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
  console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
  console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
});
```

After executing `node server.js`, I access http://localhost:8080/docs and I got

```
Cannot GET /docs/
```

Of course I already have `swagger.yaml` file inside `/api`. Any solution to this problem, please?

Comment: `app.use('/api-docs',` you sure its not `/api-docs/` ?

Comment: @Caramiriel, no it is not. I just tried it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because you are listening on

**app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc))**

and trying to access http://localhost:8080/docs. Can you try after changing the above line to:
**app.use('/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc))**